# Android - Set Text over Image

Tags: android

I want to show a picture in a view, backgrounds can not scaled so I used imageview. I need to do this by code so I tried below code:

`View2.setIcon(R.drawable.city3);
 View2.getImageView().setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);`

now I want to put a textview over imageview and in center, I tried many ways like bitmap or diffrent gravities but can not achieve that and  the text goes below image, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a FrameLayout - it piles each new view in the layout XML file on top of the previous one. You can declare the imageview first and then declare the textview with centered gravity.

**EDIT**:

Use this code in your Activity's onCreate():

```
FrameLayout framelayout = new FrameLayout(this);
framelayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams
(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image); 
iv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams
(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)); 
frameLayout.addView(iv);

TextView tv = new TextView(this); 
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER);
tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
frameLayout.add(tv);
```

`

Comment: by over, I mean on the imageview, not top of it

Comment: Yes, you will see the textview on the imageview itself

Comment: Updated answer to include the XML

Comment: I know the xml structure, the problem is to do this programmatically in java code

Answer (score 0):

If you need this by code, you can create a RelativeLayout with this config and set it elements. After, set this relativeLayout on your Activity/Fragment layout.

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout();

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

View2.setLayoutParams(params);

layout.add(View2);

params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(CENTER_IN_PARENT, true);

textView.setLayoutParams(params);

layout.add(textView);
```